# Make a tall rectangular array square

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, matrices

I have a tall array that I would like to make square. Unlike the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172359/force-latex-to-show-a-square-matrix-as-square), which works but makes the array wider to match up with the width, I would like to decrease the spaces between rows to make it square.

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{report}
    \usepackage{wasysym}      
    \usepackage{amsmath} 
    \usepackage{arydshln}
    \begin{document}

    $\left[\begin{array}{ccc:ccc}
    \times&\times&\times&\times&\times&\times\\
    \Circle&\times&\times&\times&\times&\times\\
    \Circle&\odot&\times&\times&\times&\times\\\hdashline
    \Circle&\Circle&\Circle&\times&\times&\Circle\\
    \Circle&\Circle&\times&\times&\times&\times\\
    \Circle&\Circle&\times&\times&\times&\times\\\end{array}\right]$

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, make a full example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: The MWE *doesn't* produce such a tall matrix, but rather a wide one. Do you have some “double space” setting in your document?

Comment: Ah, yes, double spacing is built into the template I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>**Disclaimer:**
Because a minimal example is missing, I do not know, where your large
vertical space comes from. I had to increase the spacing to get it square with a plain document class.</sub>

---

Usually the vertical spacing inside a `tabular` or `array` can be influenced by setting `\arraystretch`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arydshln}% \hdashline
\usepackage{wasysym}% \Circle
\begin{document}
\[
  \left[
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{array}{ccc:ccc}
      \times&\times&\times&\times&\times&\times\\
      \Circle&\times&\times&\times&\times&\times\\
      \Circle&\odot&\times&\times&\times&\times\\\hdashline
      \Circle&\Circle&\Circle&\times&\times&\Circle\\
      \Circle&\Circle&\times&\times&\times&\times\\
      \Circle&\Circle&\times&\times&\times&\times\\
    \end{array}
  \right]
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Using \arraystretch with 0.8 seems to work, thanks!