# Forcing \bmatrix to have a square form: Is there a canonical way in 2020?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, matrices

Square matrices are often rendered as rectangular due to its asymmetric contents. I would like to automatically force these matrices to be square anyway using some canonical solution, i.e.,

1. the resulting matrix ought to look *nice* for most purposes;
2. is automatic (when an additional, optional argument is given for the squaring);
3. ideally, does not require me to define new environments myself (**not compulsory**);
4. has options for various `\xmatrix` commands, e.g., x = b, B, p, or has similar syntax to \xmatrix.

Here is a example picture of a non-desired outcome with `\bmatrix`:

[image]

where the horisontal dimension clearly exceeds the vertical dimension.

There is an [older question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172359/116907) from 2014 whose answers do not meet some of the above criteria, either by [defining new environments and probably not working for various types of `\xmatrix`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172393), or by being [manual](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172368/116907) in essence. (The MWE in the accepted answer also does not compile).

I am willing to import any package if necessary. The solution should also work with Beamer.

- ***Question:*** Can the above criteria (1–4) be met in at the time of writing?

---

Here is an MWE to play around with which was also used to generate the example image.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}{Example}
        %Should look like square matrix but does not.
        $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
            a_{0, 0} & \dots & a_{0, n - 1} \\ 
            \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
            a_{n - 1, 0} & \dots & a_{n - 1, n - 1}
        \end{bmatrix}
        $$
    \end{frame}
       
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your point 3 sounds more or less like: is there an already-done package for this? If this is the question, then I don't think so.

Comment: why is 3 even an issue? If someone gives you an answer to this question that includes a definition then why is using that definition any different from using a similar definition from a package on ctan. Many packages on ctan _started_ as answers here (or on comp.text.tex and similar forums)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle An established package is more likely to have been tested by others for robustness, including for compatibility issues. I suppose it is also because I am an "end-user", not well-versed enough to modify or tinker with more complicated definitions. Any definition that guarantees 1, 2, and 4 would probably be complicated enough. So robustness, compatibility, ease-of-use (e.g., documentation), and convenience.

Comment: @campa Yes, I suppose so. Sad to hear that an already-done package might not exist. However, point 3 could also be a neat combination of more than one package if no such package has the options described.

Comment: shrug, perhaps perhaps not. You may find an answer here has been tested on a current tex system and a package on ctan was written by some phd student in a hurry to complete a thesis in 1988 and hasn't been touched since. You can find code of mine in the standard distributions and on this site, I wouldn't categorise them the way you describe.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay. I have been convinced to relax the third requirement. :)

Comment: Off topic: You use :-) the \[...\] instead of $$...$$ and the nicematrix package.

Answer (score 2):

`amsmath` matrix environments use an array preamble of  `*{..}c` you can change `c` to the `array` package `wc{3em}` so columns are all the same width, then adjust `\arraystretch` to vertically stretch the matrix to match.  this one is reported in the log as

(146.29016pt,131.40112pt)

so not quite square but visually the brackets looked over long if I forced the array to be even taller.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter
\def\env@matrix{\hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \def\arraystretch{3.2}%
  \array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols{wc{3.4em}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}{Example}
        %Should look like square matrix but does not.
        \[
        \sbox0{$\begin{bmatrix}
            a_{0, 0} & \dots & a_{0, n - 1} \\ 
            \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
            a_{n - 1, 0} & \dots & a_{n - 1, n - 1}
        \end{bmatrix}$}
\typeout{(\the\wd0,\the\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0)}
\box0
        \]
    \end{frame}
       
\end{document}
```

The `\sbox` use in the formula is just for test measuring, not needed in real documents.

Comment: I shouldn't pretend to understand how this works. Thank you very much for your answer! (+1) To focus only on negative aspects: 1) I noticed that the stretching asymmetrically increases white space at the top of the matrix compared to the lower end. 2) This seems to be quite a global option, should I redefine it for every particular matrix under consideration? 3) The vertical stretching, as I understood, was done "by hand"?

Answer (score 1):

With `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass[draft]{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Example}
    \[
    \begin{+bmatrix}[ 
        columns={3.5em, c, colsep=2pt},
        rows={3.5em, m, rowsep=2pt}
        ]
        a_{0, 0} & \dots & a_{0, n - 1} \\ 
        \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
        a_{n - 1, 0} & \dots & a_{n - 1, n - 1}
    \end{+bmatrix}
    \]
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{And the same example with rules just to show the cells are squares}
    \[
    \begin{+bmatrix}[ 
        columns={3.5em, c, colsep=2pt},
        rows={3.5em, m, rowsep=2pt}, 
        vlines, 
        hlines
        ]
        a_{0, 0} & \dots & a_{0, n - 1} \\ 
        \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 
        a_{n - 1, 0} & \dots & a_{n - 1, n - 1}
    \end{+bmatrix}
    \]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]